# WEP Passphrase mode on Linksys BEFW11S4

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have an old Linksys BEFW11S4 that I am using for LAN file transfers when I am on the road and my phone has a 3G connection. It has an option for WEP security, but it defaults to converting a passphrase into a DeFacto hex key. Is there a way to have the router accept just the passphrase instead of a hex key? And I'm using WEP because it does not have options for WPA1/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual for your product here: http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/BEFW11S4-v4_ug,0.pdf

> Instead of manually entering WEP keys, you
>   can enter a passphrase. This passphrase is used to
>   generate one or more WEP keys. It is case-sensitive and should not be longer than 31 alphanumeric
>   characters. (This Passphrase function is compatible with Linksys wireless products only and cannot be used
>   with Windows XP Zero Configuration. If you want to communicate with non-Linksys wireless products or
>   Windows XP Zero Configuration, make a note of the WEP key generated in the Key 1 field, and enter it
>   manually in the wireless client.) After you enter the Passphrase, click the
>   Generate
>   button to create WEP
>   keys.

So apparently passphrase WEP mode is only compatible with Linksys products.
The manual also seems to mention WPA security mode though, so I recommend checking if you have the latest firmware on your router.

You can find more information here: http://support.linksys.com/en-us/support/routers/BEFW11S4

Comment: Yeah, WEP *is* HEX keys. 10 character or 26 character. What you want is WPA, which may be available in newer/custom firmware. Otherwise you do what the rest of us used to do and keep the WEP key in a text file to copy and paste. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy

Comment: I've seen WEP passphrase support on other networks before. Is it just a router limitation? And also I have checked and the latest firmware does not include WPA support.